# Store and boot a cd on a HD?

Tags: boot, bootable-media

Originally i tried using a linux distro to use DD but it was not compatible with my hardware.

I have a Norton Ghost disc and i would like to store it on my HD so i can boot into it easier, not need to search for the cd, etc. How might i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to use [grub2 to boot an iso](http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2009/05/25/boot-an-iso-via-grub2/), with some craveats- the system would need to support it. If its a linux/casper disk, you could also give [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) a try - this is prolly easier, doable from windows

Comment: Agree with The Journeyman geek.  Also, if you had a server on the LAN you could use it to PXE boot the machine into an ISO.  I've seen some companies to that for their diagnostic programs.  That way the computer technician won't need to carry around CDs or flash drives with utilities.

Comment: just curious (and damn i should have split the answers)- which solution of the two worked?

Comment: ha, well i havent tried implementing it. I dont want to bother until i need to or should reformat. I think i'll go with the grub2 route as it seems unetbootin only does usb boot disc. However i am going to try that app first since it does look easier and i see a screen with the type set as USB. I am hoping it has boot partition or a similar choice.

Comment: unetbootin adjusts your bootloader if you select your main drive to chainload grub from your current bootloader - its done that for ages.You can just uninstall unetbootin, and the system will go back to normal